# Google XOAUTH2 authentication fails PHPMailer

Tags: google-oauth, phpmailer, gmail-api

Information and error log pastes can be found here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/543

I am attempting to run the gmail_xoauth.phps example from the PHPMailer class.  I have set up the credentials and plugged all the right values in a script, however I get the following rather then proper AUTH.  http://pastebin.com/U7HTxAez

This is the code I am running (with the proper authentication information input)  github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps (sorry, Rep blocked me for posting more links.)

I have verified that my webserver is attempting to connect to a gmail server. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can easily be resolved by enabling less secure apps here: https://www.google.com/settings/u/2/security/lesssecureapps

## NOTE: Use this only if you have a separate account, as it is a security issue...